# Как определить, есть ли в сообщение "-"

Tags: javascript

Я создаю бота в дискорде, и хочу что бы он в сообщение проверял есть ли там "-", сколько бы я не пытался у меня не получается это сделать

Мой не рабочий код

```js
let one = args[0];
if(!one) return;

if(one == message.content(/-/)) return message.reply("Минус не допустим)
```

Comment: попробуйте `indexOf`  помогает.

Comment: Так же я пробывал:
if(one == message.content.indexOf(/-/)) return message.reply("Минус не допустим")
Но это работало только если я пишу "-1" другие фразы с минусом оно игрнорировало.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Регулярки в данном конкретном случае не обязательны.

ES6:

```js
var str = 'Быть или не быть-вот в чём вопрос.';
var str2 = 'нет дефисов.';

console.log(str.includes('-'));
console.log(str2.includes('-'));
```

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) - проверяет, содержит ли строка заданную подстроку, и возвращает, соответственно true или false.

C помощью [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```js
var str = 'Быть или не быть-вот в чём вопрос.';
var str2 = 'нет дефисов.';

console.log(str.indexOf('-') !== -1);
console.log(str2.indexOf('-') !== -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [регулярный выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods)
Например в вашем случае поможет

```
if((message.content).match(/-/g).length) return message.reply("Минус не допустим)
```

Comment: Мне выдало следующую ошибку 
(node:6036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.match is not a function

Comment: о, простите, куда то `content` делся после `message`. Поправил

Comment: Он и вправду начал не пропускать минус, но если написать сообщение без минуса, он выдаёт ошибку (node:9992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: Я убрал .length и у меня заработало, он стал не пропускать фразу с минусом и пропускает фразу без минуса, спасибо что помогли!

Comment: `.length` убери. можно вместе с флгом `g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (message.content.indexOf("-") !== -1) return message.reply("Минус недопустим")
```